# I need a SQL statement to include address 1 or address 2 or use both addresses to create a mailing list

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have a database of young carers that have a mailing address.  Sometimes the young people have a 2nd address depending on who they live with.  Sometimes information needs to be sent to address 1 or address 2 or both of the addresses; I use a combo box to tell me which address I need to use, i.e. address 1, address 2, or both.

How do I write the query? This is the query as it is at the moment, I just need it to automatically insert the correct address!

```
SELECT tblYoungCareerDetails.Flagged
    , tblYoungCarersDetails.FirstName
    , tblYoungCarersDetails.LastName
    , tblYoungCarersDetails.Address1
    , tblYoungCarersDetails.Address2
    , tblYoungCarersDetails.Address3
    , tblGeographicalArea.QuarterStarted
    , tblYoungCarersDetails.[2ndAddress1]
    ,  tblYoungCarersDetails.[2ndAddress2]
    , tblYoungCarersDetails.[2ndAddress3]
    , tblMailOutList
    , tblYoungCarersDetails.UseAddressLabel 
FROM (tblYoungCarersDetails 
INNER JOIN tblMailOutDetails 
    ON tblYoungCarersDetails.YoungCarersID = tblMailOutDetails.YoungCarersID) 
INNER JOIN tblGeographicalArea 
    ON (tblMailOutDetails.YoungCarersID) 
    AND (tblMailOutDetails.YoungCarersID = tblGeographicalArea.YoungCarersID)
WHERE (((tblMailOutDetails.MailOutList)=Yes));
```

This gives me my mailing details of all my young careers receive a level of service, how do I now insure that they get the info delivered to the correct address?

Comment: Where is the information about which address you need to use?  You said that you select it with a `ComboBox` - where is that `ComboBox`, and where does the information go?

Comment: Have you tried a case statement?

Comment: @Limey Case is not available in MS Access.

Comment: @Remou:  D'oh!  I just assumed it was cause it was Microsoft.  What a a thought to be consistant across applications.

Comment: Thanks for yr replays, combo box is the UseAddressLabel, this query just pulls my whole list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could select the first address and the second address as a Union query.

```
SELECT a.* 
    , tblGeographicalArea.QuarterStarted
    , tblMailOutDetails.MailOutList

FROM  (

(SELECT YoungCarersID
    , "Select Address1" As WhereFrom
    , t.Flagged
    , t.FirstName
    , t.LastName
    , t.Address1
    , t.Address2
    , t.Address3
    , t.UseAddressLabel 
FROM tblYoungCarersDetails  t
WHERE t.UseAddressLabel  = "Address 1" 
     OR t.UseAddressLabel  = "Both" 

UNION 
SELECT YoungCarersID
    , "Select Address2" As WhereFrom
    , t.Flagged
    , t.FirstName
    , t.LastName
    , t.[2ndAddress1]
    , t.[2ndAddress2]
    , t.[2ndAddress3]
    , t.UseAddressLabel 
FROM tblYoungCarersDetails  t
WHERE t.UseAddressLabel  = "Address 2" 
     OR t.UseAddressLabel  = "Both" ) As a

INNER JOIN tblMailOutDetails 
    ON a.YoungCarersID = tblMailOutDetails.YoungCarersID )

INNER JOIN tblGeographicalArea 
    ON tblMailOutDetails.YoungCarersID = tblGeographicalArea.YoungCarersID
WHERE tblMailOutDetails.MailOutList=Yes
```

Comment: Thanks, will try that when I get to work tomorrow and let u know! Really appreciate yr help!

Comment: This worked, but it doesn't pick up the "both addresses" in the query, I wanted it to pick up address1 and address2, but it just picks up the first address.

Comment: It picks up both addresses, but calls then the same name, that is the point of the union query. I will make a small change to show this.

Comment: Check a.WhereFrom to see where the address is coming from.

Comment: Works perfect!  Thank you so much for helping with that, I can see where the names are now on my list!!